# Javascript error on new install of 7.0.1.0.2

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've had a good look around and can't see anyone else with the same issue.

I've downloaded the latest install for DNN (via this page https://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/relea...) and tried to run it as a new install (via visual studio development web server) but the site crashes on the second page of the wizard, I get a javascript error "Invalid character" in the jquery library and nothing happens are that.

Using the VS javascript debugger I can see in the call stack that the error seems to stem from some javascript used to update the progress bar found on the installation page, the line in question is...

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(status);
```

If I let the code run from here I get a further error of "Unable to get property 'progress' of undefined or null reference" in the same block of javascript code a few lines down...

```
if (result.progress < $("#progressbar").progressbar('value')) return;
```

Details of my installation;

Running on Windows 7 64 bit (have also tried a Windows 7 32 bit but get same error).
Using VS 2010
Installing to new (blank) database on MS SQL server 2008
Using a SQL user for authentication
Have tried the suggestion of "unblocking" the zip file before downloading
Given the NETWORKSERVICE user full control over the DNN website folder
I've tried the installation with IE 10 & the latest version of Chrome (30.0.1)

In addition to trying to run the installation using the wizard I also found that you can disable the wizard via  this web.config setting;

Running with this I am able to successfully install DNN but when redirecting from the basic wizard page to the DNN site I get an object not set to an instance of an object error on this line...

```
if (PortalSettings.ActiveTab.PageHeadText != Null.NullString && !Globals.IsAdminControl())
```

... of the default.aspx code behind

I had a play with DNN 6 last year and didn't have any issues installing so to confirm that was still the case I downloaded the last release of DNN 6 (version 6.0.2.09 from here https://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/relea...) and was again able to install that version without any problems at all using the same SQL server and running through VS 2010.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a local copy of IIS?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @ChrisHammond. I have got a local copy of IIS. I read that it is recommended that IIS be used, and a colleague has done this successfully, but I would have liked to get it working through Visual Studio if possible.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you not try to get it working through Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and switching the pipeline mode for the application pool to "Integrated" fixed the issue on PortalSettings comming on null on this line:

```
if (PortalSettings.ActiveTab.PageHeadText != Null.NullString && !Globals.IsAdminControl())
```